# Is it possible to use the elements of Array<keyof T> as indeces of T?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Hi I want to create a function that takes two parameters an array of objects "T[]" and a array of fields of the T. However I keep getting the following problem in the line where I call `el[col]`

```
    Argument of type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
```

The code is the following:

```js
interface user {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  lastname: string;
}

const data: user[] = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    age: 21,
    lastname: 'bar',
  },
  {
    name: 'foo',
    age: 21,
    lastname: 'baz',
  },
  {
    name: 'foo',
    age: 21,
    lastname: 'bax',
  },
];

function printLastName<T>(data: T[], cols: Array<keyof T>) {
  data.forEach((el) => {
    let msg = '';
    cols.forEach((col) => {
      msg = msg.concat(el[col]);
    });
    console.log(msg);
  });
}

printLastName(data, ['name', 'lastname']);
```

Comment: You are trying to access `data['name']` but you wanted `data[0]['name']`. Try `el[col]`

Comment: Hi @Konrad,  sorry my bad it should be {el[col]}. Still the same problem

Comment: `String(el[col])` works for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `T` can be an object with anything as value. You use `data[index][col]` as a string without converting it to a string, and that is the error. That is why `String(el[col])` worked. If you were to use `msg.concat('' + el[col]);` or `msg += el[col];` it would work too.

Answer (score 0):

To get types to work, you can make T extend an array.

You can then use `keyof T[number]` or even `T[0]`, seen as all elements are the same.

eg.

```
interface user {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  lastname: string;
}

const data: user[] = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    age: 21,
    lastname: 'bar',
  },
  {
    name: 'foo',
    age: 21,
    lastname: 'baz',
  },
  {
    name: 'foo',
    age: 21,
    lastname: 'bax',
  },
];

function printLastName<T extends any[]>(data: T, cols: Array<keyof T[number]>) {
  data.forEach((el) => {
    let msg = '';
    cols.forEach((col) => {
      msg = msg.concat(el[col]);
    });
    console.log(msg);
  });
}

printLastName(data, ['name', 'lastname']);
//printLastName(data, ['name', 'error']);  <-- Error
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgK4GdrIN4ChnIhwC2EAXMumFKAOYDc%20yct5hqxARtIwQDZwqRUhSo0QDXAF9cuBAHsQVZABM4YOBQzQA2gF1kAXmQ6meAgWFsA5DHnzrAGiYEWbAEwBGZxeQChJDaccFBOTFI%20OC6EgRS29mG%20bhRekfyCYFZxwQBeicgRZtFZyPEOacysKd7R-pmxpcEAHvmFeoy4MKggCGDAisgADuJgADIZAHKBADwAKsgQTZAgKujMIACe%20gB8ABRqGhSzjsgKfOgUAIJQUHAb0wDWEBvyMMizOiAc3FB62wCUUQIBzgADo7FAAKKIAAWu12ED4gMM2yBFj4EDAyGI6FoRlK1l4FjO6HB8ihsPhZ2RqPMvmxuPxONooIUPXUCL4OjOen%20RIIUj50TZ6HkGNBfHktF2zKFAqFMlww1AY0mgX26jgJx01isTlKdT1vPoQA)